# preg_match_all get all image name including its extension

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Input:

```
<img src="/assets/images/monitor.png" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
```

I used this regex expression to get image name

```
<img.*src(?:\s)*=(?:['" ])*(.*\.(jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif|png)[^'"]*)(?:['" ]).*>
```

How I can get the output like this?

```
array(
  [0] => monitor.png
  [1] => screen.jpg
  [2] => keyboard.jpeg )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved the problems with this regex:

```
<img .*?src=(?:['"])[^"]*\/\K([^"]*?\.(?:jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif|png))
```

Thanks All

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/14)

Answer (score 2):

```
<img .*?src=["'][^"']*\/\K([^"']*?\.(?:jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif|png))
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/13